# Is it possible to show the first frame of a video in VideoView without playing it first?

Tags: android

I am using VideoView in a ViewPager so show videos, and I want to show them with a preview of the first frame. But I cannot start playing them, because the user would then see the MediaController and hear the sound etc. So I can't really use `seekTo(0)`.

Are there any other ways?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, this will work for local videos. What will be the case when video will be loaded from internet (Buffering video)??

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found out you just need to use seekTo(100) and it works then!